# Pandas date format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I change a datetime format to a date format using pandas?

For example I have the format:

```
2021-11-15 00:00:00
```

and I would like to change it to:

```
(2021,11,15)
```

or

```
2021-11-15
```

I do not need any time with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a string, you can use

```
pd.to_datetime(df['column_name']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

You can use [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) for any datetime offset aliases

If your column is of datetime format, you can use

```
df['column_name'].dt.date
```